# Add one item per line using aura: iteration and lightning button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic, aura-iteration

Clicking an "add" button would like the lines below to be always added one below the other.

Today I have a problem in which two items are added per line.

**Right way:**

[image]

Como está hoje (errado):

[image]

**My current code:**

```
<div class="slds-form slds-form_stacked">
          <lightning:layout>
            <c:LookupComponent objectName="CIDs__c" fieldName="Name" campos="Id, Name" campoordenacao="Name"
              label="CID" labelitalico="(busque pelo nº do CID ou pelo nome da doença)"
              messageLookup="Mostrar todos os CIDs com essa descrição"
              placeholder="Digite ao menos 3 iniciais do CID ou nome da doença" />
            <lightning:button class="btnAddRemoveCID" name="addbtn" title="Adicionar outro CID" type="button"
              label="ADICIONAR OUTRO CID" onclick="{!c.addCIDrow}"></lightning:button>
          </lightning:layout>
          <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="slds-grid_horizontal max-1">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.listaCID}" indexVar="index">
              <lightning:layoutItem>
                <c:LookupComponent objectName="CIDs__c" fieldName="Name" campos="Id, Name" campoordenacao="Name"
                  label="CID" labelitalico="(busque pelo nº do CID ou pelo nome da doença)"
                  messageLookup="Mostrar todos os CIDs com essa descrição"
                  placeholder="Digite ao menos 3 iniciais do CID ou nome da doença" />
                  <lightning:button class="btnAddRemoveCID" name="{!index}" title="Remover CID" type="button"
                  label="REMOVER" onclick="{!c.removeCIDsrow}"></lightning:button>
              </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:iteration>
          </lightning:layout>

          <lightning:layout class="slds-m-bottom_x-small textArea">
            <lightning:textarea label="Utilize o espaço para alguma observação, caso necessário (opcional)"
              variant="standard"></lightning:textarea>
          </lightning:layout>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    addCIDrow: function (component, event, helper) {
    helper.addCIDrow(component);
}
```

**HELPER:**

```
    addCIDrow: function (component, event, index) {
    var listaCID = component.get("v.listaCID");
    listaCID.push("");
    component.set("v.listaCID", listaCID);
}
```

please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the size to 12, and you'll get one row per item.

```
<lightning:layoutItem size="12">
```